Why do analysts issue buy/sell recommendations if they also give a price target?
Example.

Tesla stock (TSLA) pushed higher on Tuesday, hitting another record and adding to monster end-of-year gains as another Wall Street analyst says there's more room to run.
Tesla shares jumped 3.6%, closing over $479 per share. The stock is up nearly 20% in the past five days, reflecting positive news reports regarding Tesla's — and CEO Elon Musk’s — connection to President-elect Donald Trump.
Tesla stock is now up over 85% since Election Day.
The latest analyst to weigh in is Vijay Rakesh of Mizuho Securities, who upgraded Tesla to Outperform from Neutral and more than doubled his price target to $515 from $230.

Given that Vijay Rakesh is providing a price target, the "outperform" (which is effectively 'buy') recommendation seems superfluous. If TSLA is >$515, then he is recommending "sell"; if it's under $515, then he is recommending "buy".
What is the point of the buy/sell recommendation if there is also a price target?

Remember that public buy/sell recommendations are marketing for the analysts and a semi legitimate effort to drive the price of the equity one direction or another. Look carefully at whether you agree with their rationale, and consider that a whole bunch of other people are going to be considering the same advice which may distort prices for a short time after the recommendation. Caveat lector/auditor.

A price target does not mean that they expect the stock to hit that price with high certainty, it's the average of several possibilities based on their predictions of future performance. Plus, they often don't give a specific timeframe (e.g. it will hit $515 in the next 6 months) but a general idea of the future price based on expectations of future performance.
Even so, having less granular "buy/sell/hold" recommendations gives a more clear suggestion on what you should do without painting a specific target. Price targets can be useful but they don't always give a clear indication of what you should do.
If $TSLA was at $514 but the price target was $515, would you still call it a "buy"? What if there were a 60% chance of hitting $515 but a 20% chance of dropping to $100? would you still buy?
So they are not always superfluous, they target different types of consumers.

The target is part of the justification for the buy or sell recommendation. E.g. something like:

I expect Tesla to reach $515/share this year, so I'm recommending that you buy now.

Yes, this is redundant. They can just announce their expectation, and investors can simply compare that to the current price to determine whether to buy or sell. But some people just want a simple recommendation, to save them the trouble of doing this research.
